# How do I load this javascript function after document load?

Tags: javascript, jquery, animation, background

```
j = {largeSign: function(a) {
        var b = $(#identity .scorecard"), c = 43, d = 105 - c, e = 800;
        this.animation(b, d, c, e, a)
    },animation: function (a, b, c, d, e) {
        var f = this, g = 1e3, h, i = function() {
             $(".sign", a).each(function(a, f) {
                  h = parseInt(e + $(this).text()), a > 2 && (d += 30), a === 0 || a === 3 ? $(this).animate({backgroundPosition: "0px " + (b * h + c) + "px"}, d * 1.6) : a === 1 || a === 4 ? $(this).animate({backgroundPosition: "0px " + (b * h + c) + "px"}, d * 1.8) : (a === 2 || a === 5) && $(this).animate({backgroundPosition: "0px " + (b * h - b + c) + "px"}, d * 2, function() {
                      $(this).delay(200).animate({backgroundPosition: "0px " + (b * parseInt(e + $(this).text()) + c) + "px"}, 1e3)
                  })
             })
         };
         setTimeout(i, g)
    }}
```

basically I'm trying to animate the background-position and have it stop on a value that's been parsed within the div .sign.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use .ready()

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  j.largeSign();
});
```

http://api.jquery.com/ready/

Comment: I like this option best.  If you use a setInterval or another context to call your function from, you won't be able to access it if it's defined in the scope of the document ready.  Much better to define it before hand and just wait until the document is ready before running it.

Comment: @ElliotBonneville it does differ slightly in that I call the function the user has provided.

Comment: It's not hard for the OP to call the function though. :p

Comment: What does "this" refer to inside the function and what does "a" mean? See my answer if you need to supply those correctly.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you're using jQuery, so here's the jQuery solution:

```
$(function() {
    // your code here
});
```

Which is just shorthand for

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    // your code here
});
```

Answer (score 0):

wrap the code by:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

  // the call goes here

})
```

Answer (score 0):

You could wrap it with [`.ready()`](http://api.jquery.com/ready/):

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
  // Code using $ as usual goes here.
});
```

Comment: why do you pass jquery into the anonymous function?

Comment: It's just a no conflict way of doing it. See the jQuery documentation in the link provided. The snippet came from it.

Answer (score 0):

If you want this to run after the document loads, try this:

```
$(function(){
//put your code here
j = {largeSign: function(a) {...
});
```

I have found using '$(function(){' is better than '$(document).ready', because if '$(document).ready' is ever deprecated, you won't have to change any of your code if you are already using '$(function(){..'.

Comment: Per the [jQuery doc for `.ready()`](http://api.jquery.com/ready/), your syntax is equivalent to `$(document).ready()`.

Answer (score 0):

```
$(function(){
  j.largeSign.apply(context, arguments);
});
```

where..

`context` will be what `this` will refer to inside the actual function when it runs

and

`arguments` can be a single value or an array of the values/objects that the function can receive as arguments(if any).

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   // put all your jQuery goodness in here.
 });
```